# PHP on one specific Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a WordPress website, and I want to implement PHP on a specific page (contact page). But I am not able to get this to work, the result still shows up on the other pages. 
I have tried to use the is_page() function to make sure the PHP code is only shown on the contact page, yet it did not work. Does anybody know the code I have to use to make this work?

Summary: Implementing PHP code on one specific page in Wordpress.

I have tried multiple combination like:

```
$wp_query = new new WP_Query() wp_reset_query(); is_page('contact');
```

And

```
wp_reset_query(); is_page('contact');
```

Edit:
Problem is solved, if anybody has the same problem, leave a comment

Comment: can you please show the code?how you applied `is_page()`? and what php code you are trying to execute on `contact page`?

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations:

Comment: $wp_query = new new WP_Query()
wp_reset_query();
is_page('contact');

Comment: wp_reset_query();
is_page('contact');

Comment: Please do not put such information into comments, always update your question instead!

Comment: you need to check is_page in if condition and use php code inside if function

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a `template(contact us template)` for `contact us` page. and while creating a `contact us page` from admin panel assigns that created `template(contact us template)` to this page.

In `template(contact us template)`, you can do custom code whatever you want.

In the current theme create a `template-contactus.php` and put following line at top of the page as:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Contact Us Page
*/

// do your code here
?>
```

[How to create a template](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/wordpress-page-template/)